# Self-adjoint and Unitary Operator in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $U$ be a unitary operator.

Suppose $T$ is self-adjoint.

Show that $T' = U^*TU$ is self-adjoint, and if $f: \sigma(T) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function, then $f(T') = U^*f(T)U$.

My attempt:

Since $T$ is self-adjoint, $T= T^*$. Also, since $U$ is unitary $U^*U=I = UU^*$.

So $\langle  x ,U^*TU y\rangle =  \langle Ux , TU y\rangle = \langle Ux , TU y\rangle = \langle TUx , U y\rangle =\langle U^*TUx ,  y\rangle$.

Hence $T'$ is self-adjoint.

Now suppose $f$ is continuous. Then we have $f(T') = f (U^*TU)$. From here, I'm not sure what properties of the continuity of $f$ I can use.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(T')^*=(U^*TU)^*=U^*T^*U^{**}=U^*TU=T'$$

For any holomorphic function $f$ on $\sigma(T')=\sigma(T)$,
\begin{align}f(T')&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-T')^{-1}\,dz\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-U^*TU)^{-1}\,dz\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)U^*(z-T)^{-1}U \,dz\\
&=U^* f(T)U\end{align} since $(z-U^*TU)^{-1}=(U^*(z-T)U)^{-1}=U^*(z-T)^{-1}U$ and the fixed $U$ operators can be taken outside the integral.

Hence, since $C^\omega(\Omega)$ is dense in $C(\Omega)$, it follows that $f(T')=U^*f(T)U$ for continuous functions $f$.

Comment: But that integral formula is only valid for holomorphic $f$.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks. I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral theorem shows that the result is true for polynomials. Stone-Weierstrass tells you that polynomials are dense in the continuous functions..

Comment: You don't need the spectral theorem to see that the result is true for polynomials, that follows from a direct computation. You do need the spectral theorem to see that convergence of the functions implies convergence of the operators.